# Difference between multiprocessing.cpu_count and os.cpu_count

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpu, python-os

Both `os` and `multiprocessing` modules define a `cpu_count` function.

[`os.cpu_count`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.cpu_count) is documented as follows:

> Return the number of CPUs in the system. Returns None if undetermined.

and [`multiprocessing.cpu_count`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count) says:

> Return the number of CPUs in the system. May raise NotImplementedError.
>       See also os.cpu_count()

On my machine, they both return the same result:

```
>>> import os
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> os.cpu_count()
8
>>> mp.cpu_count()
8
```

I would have thought that `multiprocessing.cpu_count` would be a mere reference to `os.cpu_count`, but it is not:

```
>>> os.cpu_count is mp.cpu_count
False
```

So what is the difference between them? Am I guaranteed that they'll always return the same result?
Moreover, if I want to specify a number of processes to create for `multiprocessing.Pool`, should I use `os` or `multiprocessing`'s function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer lies in `multiprocessing.context`, which defines `BaseContext.cpu_count` as follows:

```
# cpython/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py

class BaseContext(object):
    def cpu_count(self):
        '''Returns the number of CPUs in the system'''
        num = os.cpu_count()
        if num is None:
            raise NotImplementedError('cannot determine number of cpus')
        else:
            return num
```

Then, this `cpu_count` method is exposed by `multiprocessing`:

```
# cpython/Lib/multiprocessing/__init__.py

__all__ = [x for x in dir(context._default_context) if not x.startswith('_')]
globals().update((name, getattr(context._default_context, name)) for name in __all__)
```

So in the end, `multiprocessing.cpu_count` is nothing but a wrapper around `os.cpu_count`.

Comment: I would like to add that if you are dealing with typing, it's useful to use `mp.cpu_count()` because you won't have to deal with the NoneType in testing